# How to understand orbit definitions

Tags: orbital-elements, satellite, artificial-satellite

I've been reading about satellite observations (such as [this one](http://sattrackcam.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/updated-orbit-for-mentor-7-nrol-37.html)).
The writer uses terms such as these to define the orbit:

```
1 41584U 16036A   16167.96105997 0.00000000  00000-0  00000+0 0    07 
2 41584   7.5055 353.7008 0046333  41.2140 319.1375  1.00195548    05 

rms 0.004 deg      from 9 obs June 14.70 - June 16.79  (2.09 day arc)
```

What does each variable refer to, and what's the easiest way to view these on a map (either online or in an app of some kind?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as
[two-line elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)
(see also [nasa.gov](http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/SSOP_Help/tle_def.html),
[satobs.org](http://www.satobs.org/element.html)).
On both lines, the first field after the line number is a NORAD ID,
which you can use to query a database such as
[N2YO](http://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=41584).
The second line gives geocentric
[orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements)
for the epoch given in the first line.
The last line looks like an error estimate by observation analysis software.

The first convenient visualization service I found was
[Orbital Predictor](http://www.orbitalpredictor.com/home/41584/),
where I naively pasted the above TLE data with a name less appropriate than "Mentor 7" or "2016-036A."